# VSCode doesn't notice php contained within a JS section of a HTML file

Tags: javascript, php, html, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project which uses PHP within JS. However, when I'm working on it, VSCode doesn't seem to realise that it's PHP, and sends out errors. Does anyone know why this might be the case? I don't believe that it has anything to do with the code itself, but rather VSCode not realising that it's PHP. Any help would be great!

PS: All this code is within a html file, and is set up like this:

```
        $urls = file_get_contents('txtfile', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        $random = $urls[mt_random(0, count($urls) - 1)];    
        ?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function randsite($random){
         <?php
          echo "var href = '" + $random + "';" 
          ?>
         window.location.href = "http://"+href;
        }
        </script>
        <h5> &rarr;  <button onclick="randsite();"> PLEASE! </button> &larr; </h5>
```

Comment: What's your file's extension? `.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Change language mode:

**Command:  Ctrl+Shift+P**

Select PHP as your programming language.

And be careful with Imports (import correctly)

Install some extensions  for intellisense too.